# What does “one’s peers” mean in “No free man is to be arrested, or imprisoned … save by the lawful judgement of his peers” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Jill Lepore quotes a clause in Magna Carta, “No free man is to be arrested, or imprisoned … save by the lawful judgement of **his peers** or by the law of the land,” in her article in New Yorker March 21st issue that came under the title, “After the fact,” which is preceded with the following paragraph;

> “A “fact” is, etymologically, an act or a deed. It came to mean
>   something established as true only after the Church effectively
>   abolished trial by ordeal in 1215, the year that King John pledged, in
>   Magna Carta,”

According to Oxford English Dictionary, “peer” is;

1. a member of the nobility in Britain or Ireland, comprising the ranks of duke, marques, earl, viscount, and baron.
2. a person of the same age, status, or ability as another specified person.

Cambridge English Dictionary provides almost same definitions as the above.

What does “his peers” in the quoted clause of the Magna Carta specifically mean? Is it aristocrats, or commoner’s colleagues?

Comment: It refers to people of the same status.

Answer (score 1):

***[Peer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=peer)*** refers to its  original meaning of "status", the other connotations developed later:

> - ***c. 1300, "an equal in rank or status"***  (early 13c. in Anglo-Latin), from Anglo-French peir, Old French per (10c.), from Latin par "equal" (see par (n.)). Sense of "a noble" (late 14c.) is from Charlemagne's Twelve Peers in the old romances, who, like the Arthurian knights of the Round Table, originally were so called because all were equal.
> - Sociological sense of "one of the same age group or social set" is from 1944. Peer review attested by 1970. Peer pressure is first recorded 1971.

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 1):

*Black's Law Dictionary* (1968) gives two relevant meanings of *peers*, just as the Oxford English Dictionary cited by Yoichi Oishi does:

> **PEERS.** In feudal law. The vassals of a lord who sat in his court as judges of their co-vassals, and were called "peers," as being each other's equals, or of the same condition. The nobility of Great Britain, being the lords temporal having seats in parliament, and including dukes, marquises, earls, viscounts, and barons.
>
> Equals; those who are a man's equals in rank and station; thus "trial by a jury of his peers" means trial by jury of citizens. [Citation to U.S. case law omitted.] For "judgment of his peers," see Judgment.

Here is the same dictionary's discussion of "judgment of [one's] peers":

> **JUDGMENT OF HIS PEERS.** A term of expression borrowed from Magna Charta and means trial by jury. [U.S. court citation omitted.] A trial by a jury of twelve men according to the course of the common law. [U.S. court citations omitted.]

It seems to me that in Magna Carta itself, "judgement of his peers" probably meant *peers* in the feudal law sense of co-equal members of the subordinate nobility who were subject to the obligation (or privilege) of serving on a court as co-vassels of a higher-ranked lord, since that document chiefly reflected a power struggle for legal rights and authority between the king and the nobility.

It's easy to overstate the direct relevance of Magna Carta to the legal rights of commoners in medieval England, but the rather organic development of legal rights, procedures, and remedies for commoners over hundreds of years under what has become known as the "common law" undoubtedly drew some of its models from the rights that the aristocracy claimed for itself through Magna Carta.

Today, a number of principles of British and U.S. law continue to draw on wording originating in that document, now treated as rights of all citizens; and one of these is the right of a person accused of a crime to judgment (that is, to a verdict from a jury) of that person's peers—now understood, as *Black's Law Dictionary* notes, to refer to a representative selection of the person's fellow citizens.